# launching an itune music link in app browser NOT the itunes app~

Tags: ios, uiwebview, itunes

hi my app has links to an itunes music album
like this
http://itunes.apple.com/us/album/better-than-a-hallelujah/id366013643?i=366013659&ign-mpt=uo%3D4

when they click the link in my app, i want to open it in my app (i have a uiwebview), problem is that it launches the uiwebview in my app, but the page is blank, the address bar is also blank, i.e. it doesn't contain the address http://itunes.apple.com/us/album/better-than-a-hallelujah/id366013643?i=366013659&ign-mpt=uo%3D4

i think it is because it is trying to launch the itunes app in the simulator/device
but i don't care, i want the http://itunes.apple.com/us/album/better-than-a-hallelujah/id366013643?i=366013659&ign-mpt=uo%3D4 to load in the browser and display the content like you would in the desktop browser.

please help thanks

Answer (score 0):

As I got from your question, you need to display the album data in your app. For doing that I suggest you two ways.

First solution is to use NSURLRequest with the url and download it's data and load the html in the webview. (you may change the User-Agent too if you wanted to get the desktop version of the page.

The second one is using iTunes API to get album data from iTunes Store as JSON and then display the data in your custom view.
You can get more information on iTunes Store API [here](http://www.apple.com/itunes/affiliates/resources/documentation/itunes-store-web-service-search-api.html)

Hope it helps. :)